# Firestore collection flatten Observable<Observable>>

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

In my firestore I have a "m" document containing an AP collection.
I would like to for each AP in AP collection, return a the AP but enriched with a P object.
I have the following code:

```
const foo = this.mCollection
  .doc(mId)
  .collection<AP>('aPs', ref =>
    ref.orderBy('creationDate')
  )
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(documentAction =>
      documentAction.map(changeOnDocument => {
        const data = changeOnDocument.payload.doc.data() as AP;
        const id = changeOnDocument.payload.doc.id;
        return this.pService.getP(data.Po.id).pipe(
          map(oP => {
            return new AP(
              id,
              data.creationDate,
              oP
            );
          })
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

But this is returning an `Observable<Observable<AP>[]>` and I was expecting an `Observable<AP[]>`

What am I forgotting? I don't understand that sub Observable.

Comment: The `map` operator after the first `pipe` should be a `mergeMap` instead if your intention is to flatten the inner collection of observables.

Comment: @miqh I tried but then it returns an Observable<AP> not anymore an array. It seems that it flattens the array too?

Comment: Ah. I see you've updated your post with the expected type. So, if each `this.pService.getP()` returns `Observable<AP>`, then `documentAction.map()` should give `Observable<AP>[]`. If you want the latter to instead give `Observable<AP[]>`, you'll need to apply a `merge` with each item part of `Observable<AP>[]` spread out (i.e. using `...`). End result should look something like: `mergeMap(documentAction => merge(...(documentAction.map(...)))`